# Why is .call() necessary when I want to see returned values from a smart contract function?

Tags: solidity, truffle, web3js

In my contract I have this function (solc 0.8.4):

```
   function makeDecision(address person) external returns (string memory name, bool approved) {
       require(msg.sender == loanOfficer, "Only the loan officer can initiate a decision.");
       require(bytes(applicants[person].name).length != 0, "That person is not in the pool of applicants.");

       if (applicants[person].credScore > 650 && applicants[person].credAge > 5) {
          applicants[person].approved = true;
       }

       return (applicants[person].name, applicants[person].approved);
    }
```

When I go into my truffle console and call my function this way `loanContract.makeDecision(accounts[1])` everything works fine, but I get a tx receipt as the response.

When I call my function this way via truffle console `loanContract.makeDecision.call(accounts[1])` I get the expected response from my function. I am wanting an explanation that tells me why this difference in response occurs so that I understand what is going on on a deeper level. I hate using things without understanding why they work.

If it helps, my contract (which is named `LoanDisbursement`) was initialized in the console like so: `let loanContract = await LoanDisbursement.deployed()` and my accounts variable: `let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()`

any tips would help since I am still learning and diving into this ecosystem. I've not been able to find any decent documentation on this functionality as of yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle [contract functions](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function) create a transaction - and return the transaction data.

The [call function](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#explicitly-making-a-call-instead-of-a-transaction) doesn't create a transaction, it just makes a call. So it cannot return transaction receipt and the authors of Truffle decided to return the function value instead.

*Without transaction, the state of your contract is **not changed**. Which is probably not what you want, and you should always create a transaction when you need to save state changes to the blockchain.*

---

Truffle doesn't return the function value when you're creating a transaction. Using Truffle, there are two approaches that they recommend:

- Reading event logs that the transaction produced

  Add an event to your function `emit MadeDecision(applicants[person].name, applicants[person].approved);`, and then access it in your JS code in `result.logs`.
- Calling a getter in a subsequent call.

  Tx `setValue(5)` and then call `getValue()`. Or in your case:

  Tx `makeDecision(0x123)` and then call `applicants[0x123]` (assuming `applicants` is public).